# Hadoop: Write asynchronously to Amazon S3

Tags: java, hadoop, asynchronous, amazon-s3

In a Hadoop Map action, written in Java, I sometimes need to write to Amazon S3.  This is not the output of the Map - it's a (important) side task.  For performance reasons, I need to do these puts asynchronously, as supported by S3.

I *could* write my own code to do this.  But, since S3 support is already built in quite well to Hadoop, I'd rather use Hadoop's support.  So:

**From within Hadoop, how can I manually do an asynchronous S3 put?**